# SQLite not returning rows, but manual execution of query does

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqlite, parameters

I am executing this query in SQLite for .NET

```
string SQL = "SELECT * FROM EmployeeStats where TransactionDateTime = '$date'";

using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(SQL, DbConnection as SQLiteConnection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("$date", DateTime.Now.ToString(DateFormatterString));

    SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    string query = command.CommandText;

    foreach (SQLiteParameter p in command.Parameters)
    {
        query = query.Replace(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

The reader returns zero rows.

I am generating the sql query using the foreach loop. If i execute the query generated by this loop manually in the database then it returns the correct rows.

Currently the Database column for the dates is set to TEXT. However i have also tried DATE and TIMESTAMP and changed the parameter addition to this. But still the same problem:

```
command.Parameters.Add("$date", DbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString(DateFormatterString);
```

See this images showing it working fine when executed manually.

[image: Example]

EDIT. I simplified the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM EmployeeStats where TransactionDateTime = '$date'
```

should be

```
SELECT * FROM EmployeeStats where TransactionDateTime = $date
```

or `@date`, or `:date`, depending on the SQL variant; worst case, it could also be

```
SELECT * FROM EmployeeStats where TransactionDateTime = ?
```

if named parameters aren't a "thing" on that provider.

`'$date'` is the string literal consisting of 5 characters: `$`, `d`, `a`, `t`, `e` - not the value of the parameter called `date`

Comment: Beautiful. Thats been wrecking my head for ages.It was the single quotes around my parameters. Removed these and worked.